# In camel, how to return multiple exhanges by aggregate() in AggregateStrategy

Tags: java, apache-camel

In camel, how to return multiple exhanges by aggregate() in AggregateStrategy.
I write logic to aggregate two csv files and i want to generate 3 different files based on some condition, so that i want to send 3 exchange objects and i want to send it to different router.

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually return multiple exchanges from an aggregator.

However, you can make your aggregator return a `Collection` of all the CSV records, [split](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) them, then [route](https://camel.apache.org/message-router.html) them to three different routes based on the condition you mentioned.

on each route you can aggregate the filtered CSV records if you wish.

```
<route id="mainRoute">
    <from ... />
    <!-- this is you aggregator that aggregates the two CSV files' records -->
    <aggregate strategyRef="aggregatorStrategy">
        ...
        <!-- split the resulting records (aggregator returned an exchange with a List body)-->
        <split>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <!-- your condition here -->

                    <!-- send to the first category route -->
                    <to uri="direct:firstCategoryRecords" />
                </when>
                <when>
                    <!-- your condition here -->

                    <!-- send to the second category route -->
                    <to uri="direct:secondCategoryRecords" />
                </when>
                <!-- same for third category -->
                ...
            </choice>
        </split>
    </aggregate>
</route>

<route id="firstCategoryRecordsRoute">
    <from uri="direct:firstCategoryRecords" />
    <!-- aggregate the filtered CSV records into one file here -->
    ...
</route>

<!-- rest of the routes -->
...
```